# Facebook comment plugin returning "you are not logged in" error for some users

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, authentication

The Facebook comments plugin on my Wordpress site is working for some users, but not others. It will retrieve users picture and allow the writing of comments but, upon submission, it returns an error saying "You are not logged in".

Seems to limited to certain Chrome users.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Recent updates to Facebook have at times wreaked havoc on members using Google Chrome as their Web browser. This is primarily a cache issue. If you're having issues logging in to Facebook using Google Chrome, click on the wrench in the upper right corner of the Google Chrome toolbar and click "Options" from the drop-down box. Select "Under The Hood" from your list of options, then "Clear Browsing Data" to clear Chrome's cache. Facebook's help center also reports that a message that reads "Must be logged in to view this page" has been reported by some users. Facebook urges members who have experienced this problem to report it to the site's technical support staff.

Source: [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/info_12158347_keep-getting-not-logged-in-error-facebook-am-logged-in.html#ixzz2npg8Qrzj)